# Primefaces selectManyMenu - Loading list from Object

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectmanymenu

So the scenario I have is such:

I have a person that I load up that has a list of integer values that represent all of the videos that person has watched.

For example, if person 12345 has viewed three videos, it would be represented in a list as such `[4012, 2001292, 50201]`

That list can be 0..x and is represented by a selectManyMenu in Primefaces.

When I load the people from the database and attempt to edit the person, instead of seeing every video that person has viewed checked in the selectManyMenu, it shows the first one and that is it. It either shows 0 or 1. Not many.

Code:

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="editPersonVideoList" value="#{backingBean.viewedPerson.allViewedVideos}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.allVideos}" var="v" itemLabel="#{v.name}" itemValue="#{v.id}"/>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: what is the type of `allViewedVideos` and `v.id` ?

Comment: allViewedVideos is a List<Integer> and id is an Integer

Comment: so this is not possible to assign integer to a list :)

Comment: Wow... Totally missed that. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome ;)

Comment: My apologizes, because I started looking at this and maybe I am actually still missing something.

So the allViewedVideos list is a list of Video objects that is tied to the Person Object and the select items value is a list of Video objects (itemValue being the ID).

Wouldn't this be sufficient? I'm still unable to wrap my head around why it worked for a single ID and not when there are 3 attached to the Person.

Answer (score 0):

If allViewedVideos is only integer type list , then it won't display any data.
Type of the allViewedVideos should selectedItem and need to put data item label and item id format.

create a class(Ex : SelectedList) with having two fields 1. Label 2. Id. Set allViewedVideos value data to this list. Return List newList of value.

use